# Determine coefficients of friction based on the torque required to rotate a part on a shaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque, friction

I'm trying to model a part that rotates on a shaft. I measured empirically that it has a static torque of around 500 N·mm and a dynamic torque of around 400 N·mm. I want to simulate it in CAD but my software only takes static/dynamic friction as inputs.

How can I convert the torque values to static/dynamic friction values for the part-shaft contact surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to model with friction coefficients in this case, because the normal force is dependent on very small changes in dimensions and material strengths that your software may or may not support. Friction is by no means as easy as it is in the text books. The basic idea is find the force normal to the friction surface in question and calculate the coefficient with the [friction equation](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_friction).

It may be more accurate and easier to just iterate to a solution. First you guess at a friction coefficient, insert it into your simulation, run your simulation, see if your result is higher or lower than amount you measured, then guess a new value and repeat until you feel that you are are close enough to your measured value.